# c++ storing text in different index of array with sciping one or two

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to make backpack that you could put things in.
Basically I have couple options that I can choose from like 
1. Weapon
2. Food
3. Water
4. Bullets
And what im trying to create is not working for me maybe you could give me any tips ?
So I create char array like

```
char *Backpack[100];
int Numberofitemsinbag[100];
```

and I'm items from list with

```
if(choose == 1)
{
Numberofitemsinbag[choose] = choose;
Backpack[choose] = "Weapon";
}
if(choose == 4)
{
Numberofitemsinbag[choose] = choose;
Backpack[choose] = "Bullets";
}
```

But if i leave at least one block of array empty like {weapon,0,0,0,Bullets}
only weapon couts out and i can't figure out why... any ideas?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Also, `Backpack[choose] = "Weapon";` should at least issue a warning, if it does not you need to turn up your warnings or get a better compiler.

Comment: How are you printing the inventory?

Comment: Your life will be simplified if you use `std::string` instead of character arrays.

Comment: You could have a base class and then pointers to child instances.  For example, `class Item` for the base and `class Weapon : public Base;` for weapons.  The backpack could be `std::vector<Base *>`.

Comment: I'm using array because its easier for me later on to use in if's

Comment: for(int i=1; i<=14;i++)
    {
      cout << BackPack[i] << endl;
    }

Comment: 1) Why is `Numberofitemsinbag` an array? Shouldn't it be just an integer? 2) "_And what im trying to create is not working for me_" What, **exactly**, is not working about your implementation? If it works incorrectly, did you try stepping through your code with a debugger? 3) "_I'm using array because its easier for me later on to use in if's_" Typically, arrays are easier to loop through, not to use them in `if`s. 4) All relevant information must be in the question itself, not in the comments (your question still lacks [mcve]).

Comment: If i pick second item and try to print out the array my array is empty

Comment: But if i choose first and second then my array is perfect

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

With your original strategy, you'd have to check for NULL strings and skip those when printing:

```
const int maxItems = 100;
for(int i = 1; i <= maxItems; i++) {
    if (BackPack[i])
        cout << BackPack[i] << endl;
}
```

another C strategy, probably cleaner and safer, would be:

```
enum ItemKind { WEAPON = 0, BULLETS = 1 };
const char *items[] = { "Weapon", "Bullets" };
const maxItems = sizeof(items) / sizeof(const char *);

int backpack[maxItems];

for (int i = 0; i < maxItems; i++)
    backpack[i] = 0;

...

// add to backpack Weapons
backpack[WEAPON]++;
// add to backpack Bullets
backpack[BULLETS]++;

...

for (int i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) {
    std::cout << items[i] << ": " << backpack[i] << std::endl;
}
```

**But**, you are using an array of C NUL-terminated strings, and in C++ it would be more idiomatic and safe to use a std container like `std::vector` or `std::list`:

```
std::list<std::string> backpack;
std::map<int, int> numOfItems;
const int maxItems = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < maxItems; i++)
    numOfItems[i] = 0;

...

switch (choose) {
case 1:
    backpack.push_back("Weapon");
    break;
case 2:
    backpack.push_back("Bullets");
    break;
...
default:
    ...
    break;
}
numOfItems[choose]++;

...
```

As some commenter pointed out, it would be even more idiomatic to use a OOP programming by defining an `Item` class, with inherited subclasses like `Weapon`, `Bullet`, ... and keep a container of `Item`s (array/list/...) or even better a `Backpack` class keeping also track internally of the number of items for each subclass.

Comment: How do I cout out only the Bullets without couting out weapon then ?

Comment: Really if you want to be idiomatic you would have a `std::array` or `std::vector` of an `Item` object and `Item` would store the name and the amount.

Comment: if (numOfItems[2]) { std::cout << "Bullets: " << numOfItems[2] << std::endl; }

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, of course, or even better have a base class `Item` plus inherited classes `Weapon`, `Bullets`, ..., and a `std::vector`, `std::list` or `std::array` of `Item`s, but this would complicate quickly. I wanted to point him in the right direction without adding too much complexity.

Comment: with what I'm trying to do there its impossible ? like is there a way that i could skip first index and go to the second index without starting from second if u get what im saying ?

Comment: the problem with that I'm not familiar with classes

Comment: Also, I think it's better to keep the number of items separate from the `Item` instance, because from a logical point of view it belongs to the "bag", not to the `Item` instance (you could have more backpacks with different number of items, for example).

Comment: I could easily just put all the items in array and just cout them out as i want but i'm asking is it possible to skip idex in array and keep index in there

Comment: So if i had a backpack with 10 items i could always check if 7spot in backpack has anything and not have to go trough the backpack and search till the 7 spot

Comment: @PetriuxDNezinau in this case, try to get at least comfortable with C `struct`s and use a list of those, because (ab)using plain C strings is not going to work in the long term, imho. Or at least use integer constants instead of C strings. If you want a good book to get up-to-speed with C++, you could read [Accelerated C++](https://www.amazon.com/Accelerated-C-Practical-Programming-Example/dp/020170353X).

Comment: BTW, with your original strategy, you have to do for (int i=1; i <= 14; i++) { if (BackPack[i]) { cout << BackPack[i] << endl; } }

Comment: where I have used your array bounds (1 and 14), but it would be more readable to use a constant for the max and maybe to start from 0. But the important part is checking that the C string you are printing is not NULL.

Comment: I'm trying to check if the p1.valid == false and i know that default value of bool is true but somehow im getting false as default

Comment: thanks for the help guys ill just use struct for this program. But I still think there is a way to do it with arrays

Comment: @PetriuxDNezinau yes, there is: the first code snippet should solve your original problem. The second is an alternative solution still using arrays, but a bit more readable and sound imho. If you like, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, if it solves your problem, or to tell us the points still unclear.